# Looping through listobjects in multiple specific sheets

Tags: excel, foreach, listobject, vba

I've been trying to loop though list objects in multiple specific sheets, in order to check if the list objects contains data, however it does not seem to work:

```
Dim SheetsArray_Reports As Sheets
Dim ListObject_Reports As ListObject

Set SheetsArray_Reports = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Array(All_CleaningRangeReport.Name, SD_CleaningRangeReport.Name, SC_CleaningRangeReport.Name, Excl_CleaningRangeReport.Name))

For Each ListObject_Reports In SheetsArray_Reports

        If Not ListObject_Reports.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then

            ListObject_Reports.DataBodyRange.Delete

        End If

Next ListObject_Reports
```

Comment: Your if statement will always evaluate to false. Try using `ListObject_Reports.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count > 1`

Comment: The above does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looping through the worksheets and not the listobjects so you cannot refer to them in your `for` loop in this manner. Try using

```
Dim SheetsArray_Reports As Sheets
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ListObject_Reports As ListObject

Set SheetsArray_Reports = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Array(All_CleaningRangeReport.Name, SD_CleaningRangeReport.Name, SC_CleaningRangeReport.Name, Excl_CleaningRangeReport.Name))

For Each ws In SheetsArray_Reports
    ' Use if only 1 listobject per worksheet if more you will have to loop through them with something like:
        'For Each ListObject_Reports In ws.ListObjects
        '
        'Next ListObject_Reports
    Set ListObject_Reports = ws.ListObjects(1)

    If ListObject_Reports.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count > 1 Then
        ListObject_Reports.DataBodyRange.Delete
    End If
Next ListObject_Reports
```